# ABP Add User's Custom Property from AppUser to Claims

Tags: claims, abp

I'm trying to add a claim "business_id" where the value will be taken from AppUser's custom property of "BusinessId". Only resource that I'm able to find relating to this topic, covers on how to add custom claim: https://github.com/abpframework/abp/pull/7998

Problem I can't use get service for ABP's "IdentityUserManager" in the approach because it does not contain the custom property added in AppUser.cs.
I did attempt to use asp.net's UserManager instead. But there is a lot of other dependency involved like IUserStore etc.

Any pointers for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found this post's answer that really helps to what I want to achieve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70035769/abp-io-extend-user-profile/70036990#70036990

Answer (score 2):

Extend **AbpUserClaimsPrincipalFactory** and override **CreateAsync** method. Something like:

```
[Dependency(ReplaceServices = true)]
[ExposeServices(typeof(AbpUserClaimsPrincipalFactory))]
public class MyUserClaimPrincipalFactory : AbpUserClaimsPrincipalFactory
{
    public MyUserClaimPrincipalFactory(
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
    IOptions<IdentityOptions> options,
    ICurrentPrincipalAccessor currentPrincipalAccessor, 
    IAbpClaimsPrincipalFactory abpClaimsPrincipalFactory) :
    base(userManager, roleManager, options, currentPrincipalAccessor, abpClaimsPrincipalFactory)
{
}

    [UnitOfWork] // Add this if you have db interactions
    public override async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(IdentityUser user)
    {
        var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);
    
        var businessId = user.ExtraProperties["BusinessId"]?.ToString();
        principal.Identities.First()
            .AddClaim(new Claim("business_id", businessId));

        return principal;
    }
}
```