# Custom Claims Principal Factory within ABP

Tags: identity, abp, claims

I am using an iDP that provides the username in the 'sub' claim which inside abp does not mark the `CurrentUser.IsAuthenticated` to true and the `id` for the user is also null because it is not a GUID.
From the documentation I found that you can inherit `AbpUserClaimsPrincipalFactory` and add your custom claims. I thought I could override the NameIdentifier claim and pull the mapped user from the database and use that GUID custom `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory` never gets called.
Below is my code:

I have tried the below implementation but `CreateAsync` never gets called.

```
public class BaselineUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : AbpUserClaimsPrincipalFactory
{
    private readonly ICoreApiService _coreApiService;

    public BaselineUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(
           UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
           RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
           IOptions<IdentityOptions> options,
           ICurrentPrincipalAccessor currentPrincipalAccessor,
            IAbpClaimsPrincipalFactory abpClaimsPrincipalFactory,
            ICoreApiService coreApiService)
           : base(
                 userManager,
                 roleManager,
                 options,
                 currentPrincipalAccessor,
                 abpClaimsPrincipalFactory)
    {
        _coreApiService = coreApiService;
    }


    [UnitOfWork]
    public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(IdentityUser user)
    {
        var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);
        var identity = principal.Identities.First();

        if (identity != null)
        {
             .
             .

            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user_guid));
        }

        return principal;

    }
}
```

Inside `BaselineHttpApiHostModule`

```
public override void PreConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {
        PreConfigure<IdentityBuilder>(builder => builder.AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<BaselineUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using IdentityUser = Volo.Abp.Identity.IdentityUser;

public class ServiceClaimTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public ServiceClaimTransformation(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var identity = principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault();

        if (identity != null)
        {
            var usernameClaim = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            if (usernameClaim != null)
            {
                var dbUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(usernameClaim.Value);
                if (dbUser != null)
                {
                    identity.RemoveClaim(usernameClaim);
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, dbUser.Id.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }

        return principal;
    }
}
```

Above is what I ended up doing. This will find the user within the db by username and add their user id to the claims. Below is how you would register in your startup.

```
context.Services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, ServiceClaimTransformation>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to register your factory to DI.

```cs
[Dependency(ReplaceServices = true)]
[ExposeServices(typeof(AbpUserClaimsPrincipalFactory))]
public class BaselineUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : AbpUserClaimsPrincipalFactory
```

Similar answer here: [ABP Add User's Custom Property from AppUser to Claims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70233523/abp-add-users-custom-property-from-appuser-to-claims/70379564#70379564)